# React html table get row value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrq2j.jpg) I have been banging my head against the keyboard for a week now.
I'm building a webpage with React. I have a map with marker on left side and a html table on right side of the webpage.

I need to grab lat long value from the table so that map can center that particular row/point as user click on it.
Here's the code for table(it's been made on App.js)

```
      <Table style={{width:'100%',cursor:'pointer'}} id='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr style={{position:'sticky',top:'0px'}}>
              <th style={{width:'45%'}}>Title</th>
              <th style={{width:'30%'}}>Type</th>
              <th style={{width:'25%'}}>Company</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {geojsonData.features.filter((feature)=>{ return  search.toLowerCase() === '' ? feature : feature.properties.title.toLowerCase().includes(search) || feature.properties.company.toLowerCase().includes(search);})
            .map((feature, index) => {
              // trying to save lat long
              return (
              <tr key={index} onClick={tmp}>
                <td>{feature.properties.title}</td>
                <td>{feature.properties.job_type}</td>
                <td>{feature.properties.company}</td>
              </tr>
            )})}  
          </tbody>
        </Table>
```

and the function

```
  function tmp(){
  var table = document.getElementById("table"),rIndex,cIndex;
  // table rows
  for (var i =0;i<table.rows.length;i++)
    {
      // row cells
      for (var j=0;j<table.rows[i].cells.length;j++)
        {
          table.rows[i].cells[j] = function()
            {
              rIndex = this.parentElement.rowIndex;
              cIndex = this.cellIndex+1;
              console.log("rows: "+rIndex+", cell:"+cIndex)
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:
The issue for now seems be linked with rendering. under function tmp 'table.rows.length' returns null, if i refresh the page it return 55 but on startup it stays null. I tried useEffect and it does return 55 on startup but i just cant use the variable rc outside this

```
  useEffect(() => {
  rc = document.getElementById('table').rows.length;
  console.log(rc);}, []);
```

**UPDATE-1**
[full_code_1](https://codefile.io/f/4nxriQwwb3)

**UPDATE-2 **
Here's the modified code that finally worked([enter link description here](https://codefile.io/f/xpmwt2SlyM))

Comment: In `tr key={index}onClick={tmp}`, put a space between like: `tr key={index} onClick={tmp}`

Comment: Hi i tried it and it result still the same.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question then?

Comment: also table.rows.length return null value and i tried useEffect to get the row counts and it works but how can i access rc outside useeffect '''useEffect(() => {
      rc = document.getElementById('table').rows.length;''

Comment: Can you put all your code into the question? It will be easier for me to come up with an answer in that case.

Comment: https://codefile.io/f/4nxriQwwb3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some changes on your code:

1. create a variable for your list inside your component before return JSX

   ```
    const features = geojsonData.features.filter((feature)=>{ 
    return  search.toLowerCase() === '' ? feature : feature.properties.title.toLowerCase().includes(search) || feature.properties.company.toLowerCase().includes(search);})
   ```
2. change tmp function:

   ```
    const tmp = (index) => () => {
    console.log(features[index])
    }
   ```
3. use list variable in your jsx:

   ```
    features.map((feature, index) => 

      <tr key={index} onClick={tmp(index)}>

               <td>{feature.properties.title}</td>
               <td>{feature.properties.job_type}</td>
               <td>{feature.properties.company}</td>
     </tr>)
   ```

So now, onClick you will log your value because you know index of your table row

Comment: thanks, I indeed worked out perfectly, just had to access the row value through object.values.